# Selecting data spanning a range of UTC timestamps

Tags: pandas

In my CSV file I have a column  as follows

```
UTC Time
2017-03-14 03:06:44
2017-03-14 03:06:53
2017-03-14 03:07:03
2017-03-14 03:07:12
2017-03-14 03:07:22
2017-03-14 03:07:31
2017-03-14 03:07:41
```

I would like to allow a person to enter a starting time such as `2017-03-14 08:00:00` and an ending time such as `2017-03-19 04:30:00`, and I would like to select all the rows with UTC time between those given timestamps. The starting and ending timestamps given by the user might not even exist and in such a case I would like to select all the rows which have UTC timestamps within those limits.

What is the correct approach to do so ?

Comment: You should consider providing a reproducible code. This would maximize your chance to get an answer quickly.

Comment: I am sorry ? What do you mean ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use .between()

```
start = '2017-03-14 03:07:00'
end = '2017-03-19 04:30:00'
df['UTC Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['UTC Time'])
df_slice = df.loc[df['UTC Time'].between(start, end)]

    UTC Time
2   2017-03-14 03:07:03
3   2017-03-14 03:07:12
4   2017-03-14 03:07:22
5   2017-03-14 03:07:31
6   2017-03-14 03:07:41
```